# how to change tkinter button for online few seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def click():
    button1.configure(bg="gray")
    time.sleep(1)
    button1.configure(bg="green")

button1 = Button(win, text="Button",bg="green",activebackground="red")
button1.pack()
```

I tryied to change button to gray for only second than change back to green. But it won't change to gray

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind that event after the packing

```
from tkinter import *
import time


def click(event):
    if button1["background"] == "green":
        time.sleep(3)
        button1["background"] = "yellow"
    else:
        button1["background"] = "green"


root = Tk()

myContainer1 = Frame(root)
myContainer1.pack()

button1 = Button(myContainer1, text="Button", bg="green")
button1.pack()
button1.bind("<Button-1>", click) # binding event here

root.mainloop()
```

btw, solid resource on the subject, a bit dated but as an educational material - written perfectly - short :D
http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way.
If you use the Time library, the software won't work
or you can use the Threading module for multithreading in Python but This method is a bit complicated

```
from tkinter import *


def click(event):
    def loop(i):
        if   i==1:
            button1.configure(bg="gray")
        elif i==2:
            button1.configure(bg="red")
            return
        i=i+1
        button1.after (1000, lambda : loop (i))
    loop (1)
root = Tk()

myContainer1 = Frame(root)
myContainer1.pack()

button1 = Button(myContainer1, text="Button", bg="red")

button1.pack()
button1.bind("<Button-1>", click) # binding event here

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First `click()` has never been executed. Second all updates are handled by tkinter `mainloop()`, so those changes will be handled after the function `click()` exits and the last change will be seen only.

You can use `.after()` instead of `sleep()` to change the color of the button back to green after one second:

```py
def click():
    button1.configure(bg="gray")
    # change the background color back to green after 1 second
    button1.after(1000, lambda: button1.configure(bg="green"))

button1 = Button(win, text="Button", bg="green", activebackground="red", command=click)
button1.pack()
```